# Как создать метод, который принимает переменное число параметров разных типов?

Tags: java, методы, параметры

В Java можно создать метод с переменным числом параметров:
(Тип... args)
Если же необходимо передавать параметры других типов:
(Тип1 t1, Тип2 t2, ТипN tn, Тип... args) - только один тип с переменным числом параметров.
Как объявить метод с переменным числом параметров нескольких типов, если это возможно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void test(Object... args){
    for(Object in : args){
    // do something
    }
}
```